# On Motorola XOOM view.startAnimation causes MediaPlayer stop

Tags: android, animation, media-player, motorola

My code to start mediaplayer:

```
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(context, Uri.fromFile(new File(context.getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath()+ File.separator + "test.mp3")));//MediaPlayer.create(context, resId);
    player.setAudioStreamType(playOnStream);
    player.start();
    player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();
        }
    });
```

if after this I start any animation (I have different animations with different views started one after another by listening onAnimationEnd) mediaplayer stops with logcat message:

```
05-08 11:17:43.180: W/MediaPlayer-JNI(6571): MediaPlayer finalized without being released
```

Currently I have no ideas about how workaround this

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm getting the same warning.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to release the media player object in `onPause()` and prepare it again in `onResume()`